# Error Recovery in JavaCC for Qbasic language

Tags: javacc

I am developing a compiler (with JavaCC) for QBasic language and I have an issue relate to Error Recovery (Error Recovery is showing all compiler errors when you compile the program)

so I had to handle ParseException and ignore the line where ParseException occurs

note : QBasic language has no semicolons so every statement has a separated line

I have tried to try catch the ParseException in every statement and handle it by using getNextToken repeatedly until I have "\n" token

unfortunately that does not work !!

Here is my program method :

```
void program():
{
  Node n =null;
  programNode ret = new programNode() ;
  boolean canrun=true;
}
{
     (< LINE > | < SPACE >)*
     (
        try {
           n = statement()(< SPACE >)* <LINE>
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            canrun=false;
            Excep.add(e);
            Token t;
            do
            {
                t=CodeParserTokenManager.getNextToken();
            }while (t.image!="\n");
        }   
        (< LINE > | < SPACE >)*{
          if (n!=null)
            ret.addChild(n);
        })+ "?"
     {
       if (canrun)
          ret.Start(); 
     }
}
```

And here is my Parser class :

```
PARSER_BEGIN(CodeParser)

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CodeParser
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
       CodeParser Parser = new CodeParser(System.in);
       try { 
       program() ;
       }
       catch(ParseException e)
       {

       }
  }
}

PARSER_END(CodeParser)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that does not work"?

Comment: Another small thing is the `n` variable should be set to null at the top of the loop or in the catch clause.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the line:

```
    }while (t.image!="\n");
```

because 1) you shouldn't use != with strings, 2) the image could be different ("\r\n" for instance).

Try `t.kind!=LINE`.